# the issues with validation on multiple form conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am trying to test he validation conditions,

`this.postalCode == '' || this.countryName === '' || this.floorRoom == '' || this.newCustomerName == '' || this.streetAddress == '' || this.cityTown == '' || this.province == ''`

i also have `country_other` and `province_other`

`country_other` and `province_other` can only exists if the `countryName` is provided as `Other` and province is hidden, by default they are declared so they cannot end up in undefined.

wat cnditions i need to modify to check if other is selected in the country, the country_other and province_other is filled up and validation and in other case, the country_other and province can be  empty if the country is chosen as canada, because province loads the drop don to select the provinces

the code i tried is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check if the `countryName` is "Other" and if so, it will check if the `country_other` and `province_other` fields are not empty. If the country is not "Other" it will check if the `province` field is not empty. This way, you make sure that `country_other` and `province_other` fields are filled when user selects "Other" as `countryName`  and province field is not required in this case, and also if `countryName`  is not 'Other' province field is required.

```js
const isOtherCountry = this.countryName === 'Other';

if (this.postalCode == '' || this.countryName === '' || this.floorRoom == '' || this.newCustomerName == '' || this.streetAddress == '' || this.cityTown == '' || (!isOtherCountry && this.province == '') || (isOtherCountry && (this.country_other == '' || this.province_other == ''))){
  // validation failed
} else {
  // validation succeeded
}
```